# Is it permissible for men to carry gold, golden objects, or equipment coated in gold?

Tags: halal-haram, men, gold

For men, is it permissible to carry gold or golden objects or equipment or tools or such coated in gold? To carry it daily, even though he may not need it, but just in case he does.

Comment: I am failing to see why that should be forbidden? Can you elaborate why you are in doubt?

Comment: because carrying golden jewelry is forbidden- it could be said that watches too are "tools" for telling time, but nonetheless, it is forbidden to carry them.

Comment: if you use a mobile phone, you are most likely carrying gold within it, if it's a laptop or a tablet or even a smartwatch(the gold inside it isn't wearable(inside the electronics), however if the watch is gold itself that is forbidden as it classifies as jewelry. Anything else isn't a problem

Answer (score 2):

Gold or other metals are prohibited for man to wear not to carry. Anything which circles around body part is come under the definition of clothes and jewellery. Ring, garland or other things are jewellery because they circle around your body. if a man wear gold is forbidden but not to carry it up. if the tool is in round shape and you put it on your fingers or arm, this would come under definition of jewellery now it is forbidden.